# .NET is unable to find an assembly located inside the executable - how?

Tags: c#, .net-core

One of my applications are written in C# using .NET Core 6, which I distribute as a published single-file executable. From it, I've had about two users report that they've encountered the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'securifybv.ShellLink, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

However, as I've mentioned before, the application is published as a single-file executable, meaning all dependent assemblies are embedded inside the executable, rather than being stored alongside in DLL files.

For one of the users, I briefly checked if it could be due to having a mismatched .NET runtime version installed, and it wasn't, as their installed version matched the application's version - 6.0.20.

I'd like to try something, but I don't really know where to start as I'm having a hard time figuring out how this error is even possible. Strangely enough, it only happens with this one specific assembly, and there's no way of reproducing it. This only appears to be happening for 2 users out of approximately 3,000.

How would .NET not be able to find the assembly if it's right there inside of the executable? Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Are each of the user environments identical? You said that the .NET runtime matches the version of the bundled application. However, I have seen in a few cases that if a .NET runtime is not at least the same or newer as the application/libraries, it could fail to load them.

Comment: Does that assembly have any dependencies? If so, are all of these dependencies bundled into your exe? If not and the two users either don't have it  or have an old version.then this assembly won't load. `FileNotFoundException` is a catch-all; what is important is that the assembly can't be loaded.

Comment: My psychic debugging powers tell me that said assembly is being flagged as a threat and removed by the users' antivirus.

Comment: @CameronTinker I was only able to check one, as I didn't really think to do it with the other, and I don't really have contact with them anyore. Next time someone reports it happening, I'll check. That being said, the library and its dependencies are targeted for .NET Standard 2.0 only, so I wouldn't expect that to be the cause.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock The only dependency this assembly has is [Securify.PropertyStore](https://github.com/securifybv/PropertyStore), and yep, it is definitely bundled with the executable. About the exception being a catch-all - that's true, I realized that a bit later, though it seems as if there isn't a way to obtain the path it's trying to load?

Comment: Is it possible that these users have a different copy of the assembly in their GAC (GAC takes priority over local)?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I really don't think so, 0.1.0.0 is the only released version that exists for both ShellLink and PropertyStore. Anyway, I checked with one of the people to be sure, and they don't have it in their GAC.

Comment: @IanKemp Maybe, though if that was the case I'd expect the users to encounter an antivirus alert, and the error to be something other than it not being able to locate it. However, you might be onto something, as someone today showed up with the problem, and getting them to disable Norton managed to solve it? I'll see if the same thing happens with other people.

Comment: @pizzaboxer If this is in a corporate setting, likely the antivirus is specifically configured to not alert the user, so that the company infrastructure team can deal with the potential security breach. And .NET doesn't know _why_ the DLL it needs is missing, it just knows it's missing.